Verify if data exists within the queried table or not?
select * from table_name where conditions

table_name is a join of various tables A,B,C...
conditions are the conditions.
Now, I want to verify if the above table contains data with B.ENABLED='N' or not. How do I do it?

Please show us the SQL and sample data and sample result.

SELECT EXISTS (select * from table_name where conditions AND B.ENABLED='N')

@RickJames I tried a lot but I don't think it can be boiled down to a table, because my entire query is to find out whether the "joined-table" consists of the data that I am interested in.
